# Outlook add-in detect language

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I wanna know if there's way to detect the language of the Outlook app? So I can put add-in the same language of the user.
I've been searching a way on the docs but I didn't find anything precise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a COM add-in, you are interested in the [Application.LanguageSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.languagesettings) property which returns a `LanguageSettings` object for the application that contains the language-specific attributes of Outlook.

```
MsgBox "The following locale IDs are registered " & _ 
 "for this application: Install Language - " & _ 
 Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDInstall) & _ 
 " User Interface Language - " & _ 
 Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI) & _ 
 " Help Language - " & _ 
 Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDHelp)
```

If you deal with a web add-in you can use the `Office.context.displayLanguage` property.

```
function sayHelloWithDisplayLanguage() {
    var myLanguage = Office.context.displayLanguage;
    switch (myLanguage) {
        case 'en-US':
            write('Hello!');
            break;
        case 'fr-FR':
            write('Bonjour!');
            break;
    }
}

// Function that writes to a div with id='message' on the page.
function write(message) {
    document.getElementById('message').innerText += message;
}
```

See [Localization for Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/localization) for more information.

Comment: Thank you! But would you how it's on JavaScript? Because I don't have access to the Application object there I believe.

Comment: I've update the question for web add-ins.